# Error "Void type not allowed here." Please help me

Tags: java

It keeps giving me an error in "Void type not allowed here."

```
public class BugTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bug bugsy =  new Bug(10); 
        bugsy.move();  //now the position is 11
        bugsy.turn();      
        bugsy.move();  //now the position is 10
        bugsy.move();
        bugsy.move();
        bugsy.move();

        // Error message highlights this.
        System.out.println("The bug position is at "+bugsy.move());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The move() method of Bug does not return a value. It is a void method. You cannot concatenate nothing to a String.

Maybe there is another method of Bug that you want to print the value of like getPosition()?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have:

```
class Bug {
    public void move() {
       // ...
    }
}
```

If you want to `println` `bugsy.move()`, then have `move()` return the position, not `void`.

Answer (score 0):

A common way is to **override toString()** method which contains major information of a Bug object, including position.

```
class Bug{

  @Override
  public String toString(){
    return "position="+position;//If you have other attributes to show, modify the mothod rather than modifying its invoker
  }

}
```

Then call `System.out.println("The bug is "+bugsy);`